# "My late friends" — they're not dead!

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, word-usage, ambiguity

Context: We're discussing about how we used to get penalized in school for being late to classes, many years ago.

I wanted to say:

> In my old school, it was hilarious to see my late friends get
>   penalized.

Here, *late friends* is supposed to mean that they were not on time. But to me, it almost sounds as if I'm talking about my friends who are now deceased.

How else can I refer to a person who is late?

Comment: Have you considered just rewording to something like "In my old school, it was hilarious to see my friends get penalized for being late?" This would remove the ambiguity you're worried about, and would also make it a little clearer that it was the lateness that led to the penalties.

Comment: @user867: Of course not! Otherwise I wouldn't have asked. Thanks!

Comment: Amusing question:1

Comment: Late as in "the late Dentarthurdent"?

Comment: The default sense here is 'deceased', but obviously the other sense is demanded bt pragmatics. However, it sounds unnatural, and Orwell tells us to avoid such.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a different adjective, like *tardy* or *unpunctual*. Or use a different construct, like

> to see the late-comers penalized

Answer (score 0):

To my ear, your sentence is totally fine. 'Late' to mean 'deceased' is a much less common usage and no one is going to be confused.

Comment: +1 for a common sense answer. Besides, the slight double meaning tends to arrest the reader’s thought for a moment, which helps the writer in making their point.